# Get a specific triple from a list

Tags: list, haskell

Here is the Haskell task: 
You have a list of elements and a number.
You have to find the triple Just (a,b,c) from the list that the sum of the elements a, b and c equals to the given number.
Example

```
fun [] 3 -> Nothing
fun [1,2,3,4,5,6] 7 -> Just (1,2,4)
```

I've tried to do smth like this (without Maybe for the beginning). But there is a mistake while creatingGroups

```
createGroups :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
createGroups [] = []
createGroups (x:y:xs) = map ((,,) x y) xs ++ createGroups xs

sum' :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
sum' (a,b,c) = a + b + c

filtGr :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
filtGr [] _ = (0,0,0)
filtGr (x:xs) a = if sum' x == a then x else filtGr xs a
```

Comment: Here is the task... Where is the attempt?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54219318/revisions) the attempt.

Comment: @tylerweir [attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54219318/revisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you start from writing code to generate all the possible triples. Your `createGroups` attempts to do that, but it's incorrect since when applied to `[1,2,3,...]` will never generate `(1,3,something)` since `1` and `2` are either taken together or discarded.

I would recommend to use a list comprehension instead, exploiting `tails`:

```
createGroups list = 
   [ (x,y,z)
   | (x:xs) <- tails list
   , (y:ys) <- tails xs
   , z      <- ys ]
```

(If you don't want to use `tails`, you need a more clever recursive function, instead of the list comprehension above.)

You can then filter out the triples that do not sum to the wanted target number.

Answer (score 0):

I got sequences like this
    subsWithSum :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
    subsWithSum n list = filter (\x -> sum x == n) (filter (\x -> length x == 3)     (subsequences list))